# facing issue while doing calculation inside HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic HTML `tbody` which I am creating on change event of a select option, so in my table, I have 3 input fields

- `ItemName` which is `autocomplete` I am using jquery UI for that, So when the user selects any itemName I am populating that ItemName's data to corresponding fields of a table, all data I have is in JSON format
- then a user goes to next input field i.e `UnitQty` and enters something and on focus out of that I am doing some calculation
- Then the last input field is `Disc%` here I am doing 2-3 things, when a user enters some input and press `enter` I am creating new row same as above with same functionality  and some calculations are done and showed in a footer row I have named as `Total`
- When user want to create new row then only he/she will press enter otherwise user press tab and focus out from the `Disc%` and same calculation I am doing

**What my issue is**

- When user enters some data inside `Disc%` and press `tab` I am calling a function to calculate the data, suppose some times user by mistake press `tab` and want to go back to `Disc%` and create new row, so when I go back to `Disc%`  by pressing `right Shift+tab` it doses some calculation as the function `calcDiscount` runs again, sometimes if I goo back to edit the `Disc%` field then also it runs the function `calcDiscount`
- Also sometimes used by mistake put leave some field empty in table's input field I have tried to alert whenever the user leaves any empty field, but that too is not helping out

Please check out [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/wver49tj/)
I am doing like below

```
$(document).keypress(function (event) {

    const row = event.target.parentElement.parentElement

    var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (keycode == '13') {

        if (event.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]')) {
            calcDiscount(event.target.parentElement.parentElement)
            if ($(row).parent().find('tr').length - $(row).index() === 1) {
                rowappend(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement)
            }
        }
    }
});
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {

    const row = event.target.parentElement.parentElement
    if (event.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]')) {

        var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
        if (keycode == '9') {


            calcDiscount(event.target.parentElement.parentElement)
        }
    }
});
```

Please check out my fiddle I have commented all the lines there

**Note-:** after entering `DIsc%` please go back to `Disc%` after focusing out using `rightShift+tab` and see the `unitQty` in footer it auto increases

Comment: @ShridharSharma I have already shard a link of my fiddle, please look carefully, due to some issue I have not attached snippet here, My fiddle -;  https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/wver49tj/

Comment: okay, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the all the values to 0 and then calculate the values by iterating through all the rows,

like this,

```
      total = 0;
      totalDiscountAmt = 0;
      totalGstAmt = 0;
      totalUnitQty = 0;
      subtotal = 0;
      $("#tableInvoice tbody tr").each(function() {
        if (!$(event.target).val()) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return;
        }
        calc(this)
        calcDiscount(this)
      })
```

see the updated fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/pLcexr6t/

Comment: ok so you are saying, I should initialize all the value to 0 as it is taking previous values?

Comment: I've also implemented logic to prevent user from moving next until the values is filled in discount and qty inputs

Comment: hey same issue is there when i press enter after coming back as `right shift+tab` the `unit Qty` in total row (Footer) gets auto increased to double like when it is 4 so it increases to 8

Comment: simply when I am pressing `e3nter` to create new row the footer data is increasing

Comment: You doing it some wrong way, as after discount% i am creating new row on press of enter why you doing like `if (event.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]') || e.target.matches('[name=unitQtytd]')) `

Comment: let me check it fully

Comment: hey your updated fiddle doesn't work properly when i press enter inside `unitQty` than still it creates new row,please check once

Comment: Hey I have done almost every thing, here I have been stuck at only one place, when I am at `Disc%` and instead of tab if i click outside that input field it doesn't  do the calculation, please check if you get some time

Comment: you need to use blur event on the `Disc%

Comment: hey if you get some time can you please check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56831552/how-to-auto-select-the-dropdown

Comment: sure buddy I'll do what I can

Comment: I've answered your question buddy, you may check